# How can I install packages?

Tags: python, ubuntu, package, python-3.10, ubuntu-22.04

I can't install a package with the pip or pip3 command and I can't install it from the Python Interpreter in PyCharm too. I can't tap on the '+' at the Python Interpreter in PyCharm.
I get this error:

```
pip command not found
```

Comment: `I can't install a package with pip command` - what do you mean by this? Please provide more context to help us answer your question

Comment: It looks like you don't have Python installed at all.  Installing PyCharm will not also install Python; that is a separate step.

Comment: I wrote 'pip install packagename' on Terminal.But i got error:'pip :command not found'

Comment: I have Python 3.10.I can use colorama,time,random libraries.But i can't install other libraries.

Comment: Note:I use Ubuntu

Comment: If you installed python 3.10, then that should have come with pip.  I don't understand why you don't have pip.

Comment: İ didn't install python 3.10.İt's already installed when i installed Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try.

1. Lets check python installation.

```
C:\Users\User>python --version
Python 3.10.5

C:\Users\User>
```

If you get the version as 3.x, then we are good, else goto your python installation directory and copy its path and then add it to your environment variable PATH.

2. Check PIP available or not.

```
C:\Users\User>pip --version
pip 22.3 from C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

C:\Users\User>
```

if above didn't work then add pip path to PATH environment variable which would be something similar to above output.

3. Now we are ready to install any package

Just do `pip install package-name`
for testing, you can try:
`pip install numpy`
If it still throws error, try below one
`python -m pip install numpy`
if it still throws error, then you might need to clean your python installation.

Comment: İ wrote python --version and i got 2 error:command 'python3' from deb python3 and command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

Comment: But i wrote python3 --version it worked.But when i wrote pip --version i got error Command 'pip' not found

Answer (score 0):

3 commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install <package_name>
```

or maybe

```
sudo apt install <package_name> -y
```

Comment: Python modules usually can be installed through `pip3`, but in some cases there's need to install those through package manager, which on ubuntu is `apt` (from debian) or `snap` ( new type of packages developed by Canonical). Add some additional information to your answer and describe steps, what these steps do etc.

Comment: İ wrote sudo apt install python3-pip and i got error again.  Package python3-pip is not available,but is referred to by another package.This may mean that package is missing,has been obsoleted or is only available from another source              E:Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `pip` installed on `$PATH`. The following command will run `pip` without any adjustments to `$PATH`:

```bash
python3 -m pip install <some_module>
```

Pay attention to the `-m`, this stands for modules and runs the `pip` program inside the `python3` interpreter *(I don't know exact definition here, if anyone wishes to correct me I will update the answer)*

However, if this doesn't work then you may not have `pip` installed, and can be installed by running:

```bash
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Then, reload your shell via the following (replace `bash` with your shell):

```bash
exec bash
```

Running `pip --version` should now work

Comment: No module named ensurepip

Comment: I would try reinstalling Python tbh